# How do I make a colour plot with undefined regions?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have a function like

```
def coulomb(x,y):
    r = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    return 1/r if r > 1 else None
```

How could I best plot this in a colour plot so every `None` value simply gets rendered as e.g. white, and only the actual number values assigned to the colour scale? Like,

```
fig = plt.figure()

xs, ys = meshgrid(linspace(-5, 5, n), linspace(-5, 5, n))
vs = 1/sqrt(xs**2 + ys**2)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect='equal')
fig.colorbar(ax.pcolor(xs,ys,vs, vmin=0, vmax=1))
```

[image: The function plot without the excluded domain.]

but with the center area blank instead of deep-red.

[image: Center erased]

Comment: It is far better to use `np.nan` instead of `None` in this context.

Comment: @tcaswell: performance-wise, or for what reason? In terms of expressing the intent, `None` seems a better fit to me – I associate NaN values with computation errors (because they often creep into divergent unstable numerical calculations), whereas `None` simply signals that something _does not exist here_. But then again, standard floating-point functions such as `sqrt` already use NaN for that very purpose, so...

Comment: Because if you use `np.nan` it will go into a float numpy array, if you use `None` the array much be of type 'object' and all of the speed you get from numpy goes out the window.  They are semantically the same, just one of them is a native float.

Comment: Well, `vectorize` actually stores the `None` values as NaN anyway, in what seems a perfectly good unboxed-double number array. Within the `coulomb` function of course `None` is a dynamically typed object, but isn't that true of _any_ individual Python variable, including `np.nan`?

Comment: Ah, that means vectorize is smarter (or maybe dumber?) than I thought, carry on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use masked arrays:

```
from numpy import ma
vs_ma = ma.masked_where(vs > 1, vs)
plt.colorbar(plt.pcolor(xs, ys, vs_ma, vmin=0, vmax=1))
```

[image]

matplotlib has a more complicated example [image_masked.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_masked.html) where you can select the color for masked zones. To convert between an ordinary array and a masked array you can use one of the [numpy.ma.masked_*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#constructing-masked-arrays) functions

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I don't have something I'm really pleased with, but it kind of works.

First, you didn't use `coulomb` to produce nans:

```
vs = np.vectorize(coulomb)(xs, ys)
```

Ok, and then I take the minimum value of the non-nan values, and assign a below the minimum value to the nan ones:

```
vs[np.isnan(vs)] = np.min(vs[~np.isnan(vs)]) - 1
```

Using a cmap other than than the defult, like 'hot' really shows the hole in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I combined [Tim Fuchs'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021544/745903) and [Israel Unterman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021732/745903) suggestions to one that actually uses a function and properly masks away the `None` values:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100

fig = plt.figure()

xs, ys = meshgrid(linspace(-5, 5, n), linspace(-5, 5, n))

vs = vectorize(coulomb) (xs, ys)
vs = ma.masked_where(isnan(vs), vs)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect='equal')
fig.colorbar(ax.pcolor(xs,ys,vs, vmin=0, vmax=1))
```

Comment: You can use `vs = ma.masked_invalid(vs)` as the last step. This will also mask infs, though.